# Android throws the error: Unfortunately camera has stopped in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera, android-virtual-device

I have created an AVD on my Windows 7 notebook with CPU: ARM (armeabi-v7a) and set the front and back camera options to "Webcam0".

When I start the Emulator and click on the camera button it's showing "Unfortunately camera has stopped"

I followed all the answers posted on SO on this matter, but none worked for me.

1) I have checked my Webcam Drivers and it is fine as the last Version of my Webcam Drivers has been released in May 2012 and they are up to date

2) I checked all the options (Emulator / Webcam0) in front camera and back camera.

3) I cleared all the Cache data from my camera and restarted.

[image]

```
`05-02 08:03:46.653: E/CameraService(66): CameraService::connect X (pid 1051) rejected (invalid cameraId 0).
05-02 08:03:46.660: E/CameraHolder(1051): fail to connect Camera
05-02 08:03:46.660: E/CameraHolder(1051): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
05-02 08:03:46.660: E/CameraHolder(1051):   at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:497)
05-02 08:03:46.660: E/CameraHolder(1051):   at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:342)
05-02 08:03:46.660: E/CameraHolder(1051):   at com.android.camera.CameraHolder.open(CameraHolder.java:131)
05-02 08:03:46.660: E/CameraHolder(1051):   at com.android.camera.Util.openCamera(Util.java:267)
05-02 08:03:46.660: E/CameraHolder(1051):   at com.android.camera.Camera$4.run(Camera.java:1100)
05-02 08:03:46.660: E/CameraHolder(1051):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-02 08:03:46.660: E/CameraHolder(1051): --------- beginning of crash
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-107
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): Process: com.android.camera, PID: 1051
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): java.lang.RuntimeException: openCamera failed
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.android.camera.Util.openCamera(Util.java:272)
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.android.camera.Camera$4.run(Camera.java:1100)
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): Caused by: com.android.camera.CameraHardwareException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.android.camera.CameraHolder.open(CameraHolder.java:135)
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.android.camera.Util.openCamera(Util.java:267)
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     ... 2 more
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:497)
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:342)
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.android.camera.CameraHolder.open(CameraHolder.java:131)
05-02 08:03:46.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     ... 3 more
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventhough the question is a month old, I just wanted to put the solution so that the future users might be aware of this problem.

My notebook camera drivers has been locked/not working and so it didn't worked. I have connected an external camera and it worked.

All the options remained the same as shown in the image (question).

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your emulator could see the webcam ?

and please make sure to check your manifest and add 
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>`
 to it.

Comment: Followed your guidelines but still there's no different result.